# TabBar background color is changing even though I don't want it to

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I want to change my tabbar background color. I did it in the AppDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        let tabbar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        tabbar.isTranslucent = false
        tabbar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.42, green: 0.5, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)
    }
    return true
}
```

But for some reason when I click on the CharactersTabBar button the tabbar's background changes.
Is this something that cannot be changed or is it something customizable? If I can change my tabbar background color, how do I do that and why is this happening in my version? FYI, I did nothing in Main.storyboard. I will share screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See [scrollEdgeAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/3750912-scrolledgeappearance)

Comment: [if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
            
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = Constants.tabbarBackgroundColor
            navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
            navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
        }]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 15 tab bar transparent after scrolling to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899805/ios-15-tab-bar-transparent-after-scrolling-to-the-bottom)